# Как округлить число в большую сторону с учётом отрицательных до 1 знака?

Tags: javascript

Например если число

```
0.004
```

То оно станет

```
0.1
```

Если

```
-0.0002
```

То `-0.1`

```
  function roundFunction(x) {
      return Math.ceil(x * 10) / 10;
  }
  roundFunction(-0.004) // вывод -0
```

Comment: ``Math.ceil()`` округляет вверх, т.е. ``Math.ceil(-0.04)`` округляется до нуля. Потому и выводит 0. Для чего в функции используется умножение на 10? А если результат окажется больше единицы? Тогда округлится до двух, а это неправильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так Math.ceil() и округляет в большую сторону... 0 больше, чем -0.0002.

А вам нужно просто сперва определить, число положительное или отрицательное. Если положительное - использовать `Math.ceil()`, а отрицательное - `Math.floor()` - в меньшую сторону.

```js
function round(x) {
  return ( x > 0 ) ? Math.ceil(x * 10) / 10 : Math.floor(x * 10) / 10;
}

console.log( round(-0.0002) );
console.log( round(0.004) );
console.log( round(-0.1) );
```

Это дело называется тернарный оператор. 

Прежде чем вернуть значение, оно проверяет, `( X > 0 ) ?` — Если да, возвращает первое значение, если нет - второе, после `:`

Comment: `(x > 0 ? 0.1 : 0) + Math.floor(x * 10) / 10;`

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто исключить знак на этапе округления:

```js
function round(a, prec = 1) {
  const mult = 10**prec;
  return Math.sign(a) * Math.ceil(Math.abs(a)*mult)/mult;
}


[
    0.004,  //  0.1
  -0.0002,  // -0.1
].forEach(a => console.log(round(a)));

[
    0.004,  //  0.01
  -0.0002,  // -0.01
].forEach(a => console.log(round(a, 2)))
```